# storing user editable constants in django

Tags: python, django

I want to store some system constants which do not change so frequently.
I have made an settings table in my database using django models to store them but this table will have only single  entry and I change these settings with django admin.

Is there an alternate way to store some variables without having to create a database?

Comment: You really want to edit these constant through the website?

Answer (score 1):

You want, I quote, *some system constants which do not change so frequently.* For this, you can defined your own variables in the `settings.py` file (or another files apart) and use them by importing them.
The most appropriate way would be to create a new file and import them into `settings.py`:

```
SETTING_1 = "/home/path/to/an/executable"
SETTING_2 = False
```

and then, in the `settings.py`:

```
from settings_site import *
```

It will make `SETTING_*` variables (give them useful names though) accessible in the settings of your project and you will be able to change the file even if you are using a VCS (SVN, Git...).

Otherwise, you can still implement a solution based on a configuration file, editable through a custom view, but it will require to create an application to manage that. But, coupled with the cache system, it can be as efficient as the use of the `settings.py` if you are parsing the file only when it is needed (at the startup and at every changes)

Comment: I'll be delivering this solution to a customer who wont be able to go into code and change the variables. I'm ready to write a view. I'm storing this in database currently (and editing thru admin pages). But making a database table for a single row entry doesnt seem alright. so I want a solution which doesnt involve changing code. I could use file but then it wont be any better than database i suppose?

Comment: As I said in my last paragraph, yes, you can make an app to manage a configuration file and parse it into a dictionary or any data structure you want. It should take only ~100 lines and some unit tests :)

Comment: Interesting points. I would like to add that you should never import using *. Be explicit in what you are importing as variables can get mixed up.